# How do I locate non-numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

If I have a list containing both numbers and non-numbers, such as

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6p6,7p7,8,9}
```

how do I locate the positions in the list which do not contain numbers. So for the above example, I am looking for the output `{{6},{7}}`. I want to use the position command, but I don't know what pattern to specify.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Position[{1,2,3,4,5,6 p6,7 p7,8,9}, Except[_?NumberQ], {1}, Heads -> False]` ?

Comment: Something like `Rest@Position[l, Except[_Integer], {1}]`?

Comment: Ah, yes, `Heads -> False` is much better than `Rest`. Ben's answer is much more idiomatic than mine.

Comment: another option not using `Position` is `MapIndexed[If[Not[NumericQ[lis[[First[#2]]]]], #2, Nothing] &, lis]` gives `{{6}, {7}}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 p6, 7 p7, 8, 9};
```

---

All of the following

```
Position[list, _?(Not@*NumericQ), {1}, Heads -> False]

Position[list, Except[_?NumericQ], {1}, Heads -> False]

Position[Map[NumericQ, list, {1}], False]
```

return

> `{{6}, {7}}`

---

Note also that the above work for more complicated structures like the one

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6 p6}, {7 p7, 8}, 9};
```

with a minimal modification

```
Position[list, _?(Not@*NumericQ), {2}, Heads -> False]

Position[list, Except[_?NumericQ], {2}, Heads -> False]

Position[Map[NumericQ, list, {2}], False]
```

give back

> `{{2, 3}, {3, 1}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 p6, 7 p7, 8, 9};
```

Using `SequencePosition`

```
List@*First /@ SequencePosition[list, {Except[_?NumberQ]}]
```

{{6}, {7}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 p6, 7 p7, 8, 9};
```

---

Using `Cases`:

```
rule = Rule[a_, b_] /; ! NumericQ[b] :> {a};

Cases[Thread @@ {Range@Length@# -> #} &@list, rule]

(*{{6}, {7}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `MapIndexed` and `Pick`:

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 p6, 7 p7, 8, 9};

Pick[##, False] & @@ Thread[MapIndexed[{#2, NumberQ[#1]} &, lst]]

(* {{6}, {7}} *)
```